# Letter scores in python

Tags: python

Here's the given scrabble score list:

```
 scrabbleScores = [ ["a", 1], ["b", 3], ["c", 3], ["d", 2], ["e", 1], ["f", 4], ["g", 2], ["h", 4], ["i", 1], ["j", 8], ["k", 5], ["l", 1], ["m", 3], ["n", 1], ["o", 1], ["p", 3], ["q", 10], ["r", 1], ["s", 1], ["t", 1], ["u", 1], ["v", 4], ["w", 4], ["x", 8], ["y", 4], ["z", 10] ]
```

And I want to use the function " **def letterScore(letter, scoreless):** " that get the score of the letter. 
It looks like:

```
letterScore("c", scrabbleScores)
3
```

Please help, thanks.

Comment: Why not use a dictionary instead?

Comment: You should use `scrabbleScores = {'a':1, 'b':3, ...}` and call it with `scrabbleScores['c']` (no need for a function here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use list_comprehension or dictionary method.

```
>>> scrabbleScores = [ ["a", 1], ["b", 3], ["c", 3], ["d", 2], ["e", 1], ["f", 4], ["g", 2], ["h", 4], ["i", 1], ["j", 8], ["k", 5], ["l", 1], ["m", 3], ["n", 1], ["o", 1], ["p", 3], ["q", 10], ["r", 1], ["s", 1], ["t", 1], ["u", 1], ["v", 4], ["w", 4], ["x", 8], ["y", 4], ["z", 10] ]
>>> def letterSCore(letter, lis):
    for i in lis:
        if i[0] == letter:
            return i[1]


>>> print(letterSCore("c", scrabbleScores))
3
>>>
```

or

```
>>> def letterSCore(letter, lis):
    return next(i[1] for i in lis if i[0] == letter)

>>> print(letterSCore("c", scrabbleScores))
3
```

This would iterate over every item in the list and return `item[1]`, ie item of index 1 only if the item of index 0 is equal to the letter you gave.

or

```
>>> dic = {i[0]:i[1] for i in scrabbleScores}
>>> dic["c"]
3
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you explain a little in the second line: "for i in lis" ?

Comment: `for i in lis` for every item in the list `lis`

Comment: How about if I go to get the score from the "word"? Thanks

Comment: from a word? give an ex.

Answer (score 2):

As Paul Rooney has suggested, the easiest (and most efficient!) way is to use a dictionary instead of a list. However, if for whatever reason you still want or need to store the data in the form of a list, you can use the following function:

```
def letterScore(letter, scoreless):
    scoreless = dict(scoreless)
    print(scoreless[letter])
```

The function converts the list into a dictionary, in which you can then very easily and efficiently obtain the value through they key (which is the parameter that you request in the function).